# Using Webpacker in Rails 5.1 and loading image assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

So I've migrated my Rails application over to Webpack but I'm having trouble loading image assets. In the Webpacker [documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) it states that I can load my assets using the following:

```
<img src="<%= asset_pack_path 'images/logo.svg' %>" />
```

But this doesn't seem to be compiled down when I run `rails webpacker:compile`

My folder structure looks like so

```
app/javascript:
  ├── packs:
  │   # only webpack entry files here
  │   └── application.js
  └── src:
  │   └── application.css
  └── images:
      └── logo.svg
```

and my `webpacker.yml` contains:

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
```

I'm not great at this new Webpack stuff but I assume it has something to do with my `webpacker.yml`

Has anyone experienced this before? There seems to be little advice on the internet.

Ta!

Answer (score 2):

I think I can resolve this by manually importing the images from inside my `application.js`

So for example;

```
# /app/javascript/packs/application.js
import '../images/logo.svg';
```

Then lets me reference this using the `asset_pack_path`

Still if somebody can tell me a better way i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This was the only way I could get an image (that was only used in mailer templates) compiled. However, I've used another js file for the imports (e.g. `mailer.js`) in order to reduce the volume of `application.js`